# Ubuntu 18.10 doesn't have the GTK inspector and I just want a terminal border

Tags: gnome, gtk, css

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
```

doesn't work, as I don't have the Debug directory under Settings...

I have managed to use the variable tho, and got this

[image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/567363514612711424/567947253008957441/unknown.png]

( Not pasting it since I thought it would be relevant to keep it as an image )

It's not reading the color for some reason, not to mention this works

[image]

[image]

So the selectors are ok, but how in the hell would I go about to get the terminal a border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem from version to version, for whatever reason the GTK devs are too lazy to update their wikis and keep changing class names, on version 19.04 BETA UBUNTU ( **GTK 2.24.8** ) all you have to do to add a pretty border to your terminal is :

```css
terminal-window decoration {
    border-: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

It wasn't working for me **because of the !important** or... hell knows, but this is what works on most versions. Don't even ask me how to get GTK Inspector working, to this date I have not managed to do that, and the wiki is useless.

If anyone has the same issue as me with the debug, run this `sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev`

> Some people instead of terminal-window have Terminalwindow or
>   TerminalWindow or Terminal-Window  (again, don't ask why, no one has a
>   clue as of why )

Answer (score 1):

It's there, just a little hard to find.

- Set `gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true`
- Open `gnome-terminal` and click on the settings menu in the top right corner
- Select `Advanced`, then `Inspector`.

[Using inspector to find the border attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDhET.png)
[image]

*gnome-terminal: 3.32.1*; *gtk3: 3.24.8-1*

Comment: Here's what I get 

https://i.imgur.com/undefined.png

https://i.imgur.com/bFKpVCB.png

It isn't about being hard to find, it's not there. It literally doesn't exist